# How to make PS script show host names as well as the IP

Tags: powershell, scripting, ip, hostname

This is the code I'm using to show mutiple IP addresses in one sitting.

I want the code to be able to show Host names as well with the same results of this code.

It will tell you if the IP is up or if it's down. ( running or not running). I'm not sharp with Powershell scripting but i'm learning slowly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$names = Get-Content "C:\Users\jason.darby\Desktop\useful scripts\ip.txt"
foreach ($name in $names) {
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $name -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
        Write-Host "$name is UP" -ForegroundColor Green
        $Output += "$name is UP" + "`n"
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "$name is DOWN" -ForegroundColor Red
        $Output += "$name is DOWN" + "`n"
    }
}
Start-Sleep -s 10
```

Comment: well that was quick lol

Comment: That was all I had to do ?  Thank you

Comment: Yes - just add code fences (three consecutive backticks) on a separate line before and after your code block :)

Comment: any Idea how to solve the question?

Comment: It shows the IP only I would like for it to pull the host name as well.

Comment: 192.168.xxx.xxx is UP
192.168xxx.xxx is DOWN
192.168xxx.xxx is UP
192.168.xxx.xxx is UP DOWN

Comment: You can do a reverse DNS lookup with: `Resolve-DnsName 192.168.0.1 -Type PTR`, the `NameHost` property of the resulting output will have the resolved host name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows you can use [the `Resolve-DnsName` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsclient/resolve-dnsname) to perform a reverse DNS lookup for the IP:

```
# read ip addresses from file
$IPs = Get-Content "C:\Users\jason.darby\Desktop\useful scripts\ip.txt"

# let's collect the output in an array instead of a string
$output = @()

foreach ($IPAddress in $IPs) {
    # Resolve host name via reverse dns
    $hostname = try {
        (Resolve-DnsName $IPAddress -Type PTR -QuickTimeout).NameHost
    } catch {
        # Output "UNKNOWN" if the name resolution fails
        'UNKNOWN'
    }

    # ping the IP address
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $IPAddress -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
        $status = "$IPAddress [$hostname] is UP"
        Write-Host $status -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    else {
        $status = "$IPAddress [$hostname] is DOWN"
        Write-Host $status -ForegroundColor Red
    }

    # Collect status message to output array
    $Output += $status
}
Start-Sleep -s 10
```

Comment: Dude!  that's awsome thank you

Comment: I did at least attempt to figure out where to put the Resolve-DNS

Comment: Failed each time  did manage to get it to do a little something though which seems like I was on the right track.

Comment: @Drone43 it's only going to work if you have reverse DNS in place for that network segment. If this is the network of your home router you're testing against, you probably won't have much luck.

Comment: @Drone43 If my answer solves your problem, consider marking it "accepted" by clicking the checkmark to the left. If you found a different solution on your own, please update the answer you posted with details about _what the solution was_ :)

Comment: gotcha  Thank You. maybe i'll obtain your knowledge one day lol